# Converting str to int python

Tags: python, string, parsing, int

I am trying to convert a str from a read file but it doesn't seem to be working and i have to use that int to take away from another...

I have tried int(variable) but that doesn't work be working..

wrote this on my phone so sorry for any mistakes

I am saving this int from start to a .txt then reopening and reading it again/ writing (save file)

```
def save():
hp = 20
hp1 = str(hp)
a1 = open("saves\DQ1", "w")
a1.write(hp1)

def load():
a1 = open("saves\DQ1", "r")
hp = a1.read()
```

---

```
hp = hp - gbatk
```

.

Comment: What's the error that appears?

Comment: Its not converting into an int

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Please post the file, your code, and the result

Comment: You should post the content of your file and your code.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know too much about the problem and you're posting from your phone, I'll start with a simple solution. See if this works for you:

```
answer = []
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
  for line in infile:
    answer.extend([int(i) for i in line.strip().split()])
```

Comment: No need for `.strip()` if you're using `.split()`.